# Exporting files from SVN and sending to a zip file

Tags: svn, zip

I'm trying to export certain files (and revisions) from SVN and send them to a zip file.  I've tried something like this:

```
svn export http://svnserver/myfiles/@747 > zip INF-2.zip -
```

But I get "svn: invalid option:"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in empty folder, you can simply `zip` all:

```
svn export http://svnserver/myfiles/@747; zip INF-2.zip *
```

If not, you can export to folder, list the content of it and pipe it to `zip` command:

```
svn export http://svnserver/myfiles/@747 export_folder; cd export_folder; ls | zip ../INF-2.zip -@; cd ..
```